# How is the Spark master elected in a Datastax Enterprise cluster?

Tags: apache-spark, datastax

How is the Spark master elected in a Datastax Enterprise cluster? I have looked at the configurations in `/etc/dse/dse-env.sh` and `/etc/dse/spark/spark-defaults.conf` and `/etc/dse/spark/spark-env.sh`. But I cannot find it any of those locations?

On our cluster the Spark master keeps on moving from one node to another after the restart of the services?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In DSE 4.6, the Spark Master / Hadoop Job Tracker (always on the same node) are determined by a round robin algorithm and are stored in jobtracker table. This may change in future releases.

You can check and see what your current master is is by using:

```
dsetool listjt
```

This will output your current master and the reserve master if one has been configured.

To configure a reserve master use:

```
dsetool reservejt
```

Output might look something like this:

```
 $ dsetool listjt DC                             JobTracker   
 --                             --            
 Analytics-Analytics            192.168.101.122 
 ------ Reserve-JT = 192.168.101.121
```