# Trouble finding Spark master with DSE 4.7

Tags: cassandra, apache-spark, datastax-enterprise

I upgraded to DSE 4.7, and now the Spark master address seems to have been reset. When I try to run spark using `dse spark`, I get:

```
java.io.IOException: Spark Master address cannot be retrieved. This really should not be happening with DSE 4.7+ unless your cluster is over 50% down or booted up in the last minute.
    at com.datastax.bdp.plugin.SparkPlugin.getMasterAddress(SparkPlugin.java:257)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at sun.reflect.misc.Trampoline.invoke(MethodUtil.java:75)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor4.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
```

Same error when I run `dsetool sparkmaster`. Is it possible to manually set the master in a conf somewhere? There seem to be many configuration file Any help appreciated.

Comment: you can always set the master via --master=..., but your underlying problem seems a bit more dangerous ...

Comment: I just discovered the problem is once again OpsCenter. When I try to provision an Analytics node from OpsCenter, I can see in the post request that the actual node provisioned is 'cassandra' instead of 'analytics', set in the param node_type_counts.

Comment: Hi, can't find a way to determine spark-master location. I just enable spark in /etc/default/dse configuration and spark starts. I would like to understand the way DSE assigns master

Comment: Maybe this will help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29558584/how-is-the-spark-master-elected-in-a-datastax-enterprise-cluster

Comment: @RussS Can you clarify the full command to set spark master?