# where is the spark master saved in DSE 4.8.5+

Tags: apache-spark, datastax-enterprise

previous question 
[How is the Spark master elected in a Datastax Enterprise cluster?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29558584/how-is-the-spark-master-elected-in-a-datastax-enterprise-cluster)
talks about jobtracker table. But i couldnt find any. Where is this table stored. is it still applicable in 4.8.5.

Answer (score 0):

In DSE 4.8.x you can read the current master from a table in the `dse_system` keyspace:

```
cqlsh> select * from dse_system.real_leaders ;

 army     | datacenter | address
----------+------------+-----------
 HadoopJT |  Analytics | 127.0.0.3

(1 rows)
```

**Caution:** this is an internal implementation detail which can (and does) change from release to release.